# Is there a reason why this join configuration returns no results?

Tags: sql-server

(See table join configuration below)

I am trying to pull similar data from 2 separate tables to do a "summary."
I am trying to return "story_height" from the dwellings table, and "number_floors" from the comm_bldg table.  The data in those fields are the same (1.0, 1.5, 2.0, etc)  EDIT: The data in those fields is NOT the same.

If I restrict the joins to ONE or THE OTHER,(dwellings or comm_bldg) I get the results I want, but just from THAT table.

extension values such as R01, R02, etc will only match with the dwellings table, while extension values such as C01, C02, will only match with the comm_bldg table.

However, I need a result that gives me results from BOTH.
I apologize if this is a "noob" question... but it's been a long time since I've tried to do anything like this, and my brain is fried.  EDIT:  I've added some example data to hopefully illustrate better.  (The tables display properly in my preview, but not once I post, for some reason)

TABLE "extensions" EXAMPLE

| lrsn | extension |
| --- | --- |
| 00001 | R01 |
| 00002 | R02 |
| 00003 | C01 |
| 00004 | C02 |

TABLE "dwellings" EXAMPLE

| lrsn | extension | story_height |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 00001 | R01 | 1.0 |
| 00002 | R02 | 1.5 |

TABLE "comm_bldg" EXAMPLE

| lrsn | extension | number_floors |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 00003 | C01 | 1.0 |
| 00004 | C02 | 2.0 |

WHAT I NEED FOR COMBINED FINAL RESULT:

| lrsn | extension | FLOORS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 00001 | R01 | 1.0 |
| 00002 | R02 | 1.5 |
| 00003 | C01 | 1.0 |
| 00004 | C02 | 2.0 |

[image: table joins diagram]

Comment: Possibly using INNER JOIN instead of LEFT JOIN?

Comment: INNER JOIN didn't work, either, but thanks.

Comment: It is difficult to help based on a diagram and a confusing description. No one but you knows exactly what you are modelling, what your tables actually represent, and what the relationships are between them. You mention "joins" (which suggest a query issue) but you only post a diagram (which suggests a schema / design issue). Given the <one or other> comment, it seems you might have a type-of schema issue that might be better addressed as a hierarchical (parent-child) relationship.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

update : You will have to cast if both story_height and number_floors are different datatype.

```
select e.lrsn, d.extension, cast(story_height as numeric(5,2))  as floor
from extensions e
join dwellings d on e.lrsn = d.lrsn and e.extension = d.extension
union
select e.lrsn, c.extension, cast(number_floors as numeric (5,2) ) as floor
from extensions e
join comm_bldg c on e.lrsn = c.lrsn and e.extension = c.extension
```

Comment: I think this might work, but it errors because it turns out that story_height is char(5) and number _floors is int - and I cant remember the exact syntax to convert one to the other.  (I'll start looking through other queries to see if I can find some)

Comment: what you are looking for is cast. I have updated the query.

Comment: THANKS!  Since I don't need floor to be an actual number (it's just for a report) I ended up converting both to varchar...

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing this...

```
select e.lrsn, d.extension, cast(story_height as varchar(5))  as floor
from extensions e
join dwellings d on e.lrsn = d.lrsn and e.extension = d.extension
union
select e.lrsn, c.extension, cast(number_floors as varchar(5)) as floor
from extensions e
join comm_bldg c on e.lrsn = c.lrsn and e.extension = c.extension
```